# Why is my custom ListCellRenderer ignoring my calls to setText?

Tags: java, swing, jlist, listcellrenderer

I created a custom ListCellRenderer that extends Jidesoft's StyledLabel. The JList my renderer is used in is a fixed width, so in my renderer I attempt to shorten text based on this width. I call setText in getListCellRendererComponent, which sometimes works. When I select a cell, the text acts as if I had never shortened it at all. There is no branching related to the setText and text-shortening.

I attempted to use the solutions in [this somewhat-related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13473592/2733569) discussing custom rendering and cell heights, but it didn't work consistently on select either.

edit: some code

```
public class CustomListCellRenderer extends StyledLabel implements ListCellRenderer {

    public Component getListCellRendererComponent(
        JList list, 
        Object value, 
        int index, 
        boolean isSelected, 
        boolean cellHasFocus)   {
    setText(shortenName(value.toString(), 150));

    return this;
}

    private String shortenName(String name, int width)  {
    if(this.getGraphics() != null)  {
        final FontMetrics fontMetrics = this.getFontMetrics(this.getFont());

        String end = name.substring(name.length()/2);
        String beginning = name.substring( 0, name.length()/2);

        int stringWidth = SwingUtilities.computeStringWidth(fontMetrics, name);

        if(stringWidth < width)
            return name;

        do  {
            end = end.substring(1);
            beginning = beginning.substring(0, beginning.length() - 1);

            stringWidth = SwingUtilities.computeStringWidth(fontMetrics, beginning + "..." + end);
        } while (stringWidth > width);
        return beginning + "..." + end;
    }
    return name;
   }
    public static void main(String[] args)  {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    JList list = new JList(new String[] {
            "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
            "yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy",
            "zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz"});
    list.setCellRenderer(new CustomListCellRenderer());
    frame.getContentPane().add(list);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

Comment: We find it extremely difficult to debug your code when you don't show us any of your code.

Comment: @Takendarkk added some code.

Comment: Don't know why you are extending StyledLabel. All you are doing is trying to set the text so why not extend the default renderer? Don't forget to invoke `super.getListCellRendererComponent(...)` so you get the default highlighting behaviour. I wouldn't hardcode the width of the string. The width should be based on the width of the JList.

Comment: I need the StyledLabel for styling later on in the project, what I posted here is an extremely simplified version. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your implementation of `ListCellRenderer` you're relying on the `getGraphics()` of the label. Sometimes, `getGraphics()` is `null` which is OK, but you're not entering the `if(this.getGraphics() != null)` condition and simply returning the unmodified string. That is why you get inconsistent results. Commenting out this condition solved the problem in the posted code. You should not rely on `getGraphics()` its value is out of your control.

Comment: How else can I use the FontMetrics then? Or should I abandon this approach?

Comment: @tM-- not sure what you mean. you get `FontMetrics` using `getFontMetrics()`. Just don't condition it on `if(this.getGraphics() != null)`.

Comment: Sorry I thought getFontMetrics() relied on getGraphics() for some reason. Removing that condition worked - thank you.